# Calculating the eccentricity for the ellipse.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, conic-sections

I am trying to calculate the eccentricity of an ellipse given by the equations:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
x(t) = 2\cos(t) + 1,\\\\
y(t) = 3\sin(t)- 2
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
where $t\in[0,2\pi]$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome.  In what situations *are* you able to calculate an ellipse's eccentricity?  Can you transform this situation into one of those?

Comment: What is the length of the major / minor (or semi-major / minor) axes?  How do you find the eccentricity, if you know these values?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

According to the fundamental trigonometric identity $\cos^{2}(\theta) + \sin^{2}(\theta) = 1$, the following relation holds:
\begin{align*}
\frac{(x-1)^{2}}{4} + \frac{(y+2)^{2}}{9} = 1
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The points on that kind of ellipse can be expressed as
$$
\left(\frac{x - x_0}{a}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{y - y_0}{b}\right)^2 = 1
$$